# Google App Engine Custom Domain not working | DNS records could not be found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, dns, cloudflare, custom-domain

I have been struggling to complete the creation of a subdomain for Google Cloud's App Engine.

The website is hosted on zen.co.uk

The DNS records are on Cloudflair

I have got as far as adding a subdomain and adding Google's suggested DNS records to Cloudflair in various combinations but the Google-managed SSL Security says the DNS records cannot be found?

You can view the Custom Domain on Google Cloud's App Engine [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbC37.jpg)

You can view the cloudflair scenario 1 (adding of A records & AAAA records) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3kDq.jpg)

You can view the cloudflair scenario 2 (adding of CNAME record) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqUdn.jpg)

Cloudflair have advised me that I cannot add a CNAME record if I've used A & AAAA records - does that make sense?

Google have advised me that "always use HTTPS" must be switched off on the SSL/TLS Edge Certificate which I can confirm it is.

When I call up the subdomain (googlecloud.xxxxxxxxxx.com) in a browser it says the handshake failed - see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouI6G.jpg)

Can anybody advise me as to why Google is saying the DNS records cannot be found? Are there other parameters that need setting up in order to make this work?

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: IIRC you cannot use Cloudflare's Proxied DNS configuration with Google custom domains during the time the certificate is being issued. Once the cert is issued, you can switch back to Proxied. However, Google will not renew the certificate and you are back in the endless loop. Tip: I am not aware of enough benefits to using Cloudflare's proxy features for Google services backed by the GFE (Cloud Run, App Engine, etc). They step on each other in too many ways. The biggest issue is DNS.

Comment: Hi @John Hanley - That's good to know. I moved over to Cloudflair as was advised to by a company I work with as it allowed me to set up a Custom Domain replacing their domain name with mine (if I have the language right, I think that might be "as a proxy"). If I have to move back to where the domain name is kept, then I'll need to understand how to set up the Custon Domain/Proxy on their DNS records. Hopefully they'll be helpful in setting that up & then I presume from your comment that I should be able to set up a Custom Domain for the GC App Engine. Let's see

Comment: I recommend using Google Cloud DNS for Google services.

Comment: Hi @John Hanley: I have just spoken to my original hosting company (zen.co.uk) about moving the DNS records back to their customer portal but they've advised me that I cannot us proxied record on their system. Can I ask... since you suggested using Google Cloud DNS - if I was to do that, would I be able to setup proxied records on that system?

Comment: You can use Cloud DNS, but you would not be able to use Cloudflare proxy features. One solution is to delegate a subdomain to Cloud DNS and have the parent domain at Cloudflare.